# Hover effect applies to all images

Tags: html, css

I have this code here:

```css
#mg1 {
  margin-left: 3%;
}
#mg1:hover {
  margin-top: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
  <center>
    <div id="bgp">
      <center>
        <p>THUMBNAILS</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>
  <br>

  <img src="321321321321.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg1">
  <img src="ewqfh.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg2">
  <img src="2321321.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg3">

</div>
```

The hover effect should only affect the image with the id="mg1", but instead it affects all my images; Why is this happening?

Comment: When you are changing the margins for `#mg1`, you are affecting neighboring images as well. The images all share the same 3rd dimension.

Comment: I have added the answer you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#mg1{
margin-left:3%;
position:relative;
}

#mg1:hover{
 
margin-top:4%;
}
   
img{

  float:left;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
       <center><div id="bgp"><center><p>THUMBNAILS</p></center></div></center><br>

        <img src="321321321321.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg1">

        <img src="ewqfh.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg2">
        <img src="2321321.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg3">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#section1{
position:relative;
}
#mg1,#mg2,#mg3{
position:absolute;
}
#mg1{
margin-left:3%;
}
#mg2{
top:200px;
  
}
#mg3{
left:200px;
  
}

#mg1:hover{
  margin-top:15%;
  transition:2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
       <center><div id="bgp"><center><p>THUMBNAILS</p></center></div></center><br>
<div id="mg1">
        <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-humming-bird-png-4.png" width="200" height="150" ></div>
       <div id="mg2"> <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/guitar-icon-png-18.jpg" width="200" height="150" ></div>
     <div id="mg3">   <img src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/super-mario-03.png" width="200" height="150" ></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `position:relative` and **`z-index:1`** to `#mg1`. and use `top` and `left` properties instead of `margin`s, and instead of percentages, use `vh` and `vw` if your parent element is too small.

#### SNIPPET

```css
#section1 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}
#mg1:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 4vh;
  left: 3vw;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
  <center>
    <div id="bgp">
      <center>
        <p>THUMBNAILS</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>
  <br>

  <img src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg1">
  <img src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg2">
  <img src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg3">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mg1 {
  margin-left: 3%;

}
#mg1:hover {
  margin-top: 4%;    
}

img{
position: relative;
float : left;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="section1">
  <center>
    <div id="bgp">
      <center>
        <p>THUMBNAILS</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>
  <br>

  <img src="321321321321.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg1">
  <img src="ewqfh.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg2">
  <img src="2321321.png" width="200" height="150" id="mg3">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pleas explain you answer, code-only answers might not be that useful for others.